# Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC): How many samples are needed to get a uniform sample?

Tags: r, markov-process, uniform-distribution

I am interested in a general answer although my question is rooted in a specific document. I am using the R package "hitandrun":

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hitandrun/hitandrun.pdf

On page 2, the author states that $0^*(n^3)$ samples are needed to get a uniform sample. I know the dimension of the sampling space $n$ but I don't know what is meant with $0^*$.

Comment: I think it is the notation for *order of magnitude* asymptoticaly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: It's big O notation (omega). Ω(n3).

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comments! Do you know how $0^*(n^3)$ is to be interpreted than? Is it just $n^3$ or $n^3$ times the order of magnitude?